# Show results from multiple Hudson build servers

Tags: hudson

In our company we use Hudson for our CI-servers. We have a separate server running for each current project (there is usually between 3 and 10 ongoing projects).

We would like to setup a monitor in a central location that shows the status for all the build servers at once.

I guess this has been done before, so is there anything premade to collecting and displaying this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Build+Publisher+Plugin

You can publish stuff (artifacts, results, etc) from multiple Hudson servers onto a single server.